# Rails4: Access child object in parent while creating parent from child form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, rails-activerecord

I have associations as

Delivery Model

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :deliveries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedule
end
```

Schedule Model

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deliveries, inverse_of: :schedule
  include PushUpdates

  def offer
    deliveries.last.try(:offer)
  end
end
```

PushUpdates: app/model/concerns/push_updates.rb

```
module PushUpdates
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_create {update_client_store :create unless Rails.env.test? }
    after_update {update_client_store :update unless Rails.env.test? }
  end

  def update_client_store(operation)
    ...
    self.offer
  end
end
```

Now, while saving delivery, am also accepting the one set of schedule details.

and when it saves delivery and schedule, there is `after_create` callback called for schedule model, and when it tries to find out the `deliveries.last` it gives `nil` value.
Since am accepting it as a part of nested attributes, then delivery object should be available for it but still it gives `nil` value.

Am I missing anything here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that Rails is trying to make a database call before the associated records have been committed.

There is an additional callback that you could look at `after_commit` (in place of `after_create` that is fired once the records have been committed to whatever database you are using.

That should mean that your `deliveries.last` should come back non-empty. You could also force a database lookup on the model with `self.reload`, although that could cause unexpected behaviour.